# how can i show portrait view from landscapeview(iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, landscape-portrait

I am writing app for iPhone. It works fine but in iPad it does not scale correctly. I have landscape view and I did it programatically. Then i am doing push. Then it shows this:

[image]

i want it to rotate and fullscreen. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which IOS version Are you working..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check and implement Orientation in ios6 or ios5 like bellow code And information Put Method in Each Class:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**and check every time in `ViewWillApear` device Oriantation like:-**

```
- (void)willRotateToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newOrientation {
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

              //set your landscap View Frame
                [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

            }



        }
        else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
      //set your Potrait View Frame
                [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

            }
        }
        // Handle rotation
    }


    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [self willRotateToOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];  
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

likely people use checking device`orientation` like below way in putting this line in to `ViewWillApear`:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceRotated:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

**and**

```
-(void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //Do your stuff for landscap
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
      //Do your stuff for potrait

    }

}
```

**IN IOS5 only landscap you can do like bellow:**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {


        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

**if you wish to support all oriantation you need to just return YES  like:-**

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

            return YES;  
    }
```

Comment: Cool, great. Thanks and More Thanks!